# Cast Nvarchar to Int Failing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some rows I'm trying to cast to integer to get the last number in sequence.

This is my original query.

```
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT)) + 1
FROM InventoryItem ii
JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid
  ON ii.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode
WHERE iid.DepartmentCode = 'Filters'
AND ItemName LIKE 'CA4%____'
AND CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT) < 41000
```

However I get an error message:
    `Error (1,1): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '41020-S' to data type int.`

Obviously, I'm aware what this message means. However I'm confused why its throwing the error, as the `WHERE` clauses I've specified are for the sole purpose of excluding records which might fail the cast.

If I modify the query to just select the original values, without any replacing or casting...

```
SELECT
  ItemName
FROM InventoryItem ii
JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid
  ON ii.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode
WHERE iid.DepartmentCode = 'Filters'
AND ItemName LIKE 'CA4%____'
```

This returns some data like so:

```
CA40000
CA40001
CA40002
CA40003
CA40004
CA40005
.... etc
```

The troublesome value '41020-S'   (Originally 'CA41020-S' after the Replace)  isn't included in the second debug result set, as I'd expected.

Can anyone help me explain this weird behaviour, and how I might possibly overcome it?

Comment: Actually it fails at the `WHERE` clause as it try to convert the value `41020-S` to Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two learning points here:

1. Avoid using `CAST` and `CONVERT` in `WHERE` expressions wherever possible - they fragilize the query and reduce performance due to performing conversions on rows which will be excluded.
2. `MAX()` also works with string values.

Assuming the values from which you want to find the maximum are in the range CA40000 to CA40999 and the data are well formed, apart from the occasional suffix like the *41020-S* which broke your query, you could use :

`SELECT CAST(MAX(SUBSTRING(ItemName, 3, 5)) AS INT) + 1
 FROM InventoryItem ii
   INNER JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid
     ON ii.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode
 WHERE iid.DepartmentCode = 'Filters'
  AND ItemName LIKE 'CA40___%'`

In a very large table, `MAX(LEFT(ItemName, 7))` might be faster, because it can directly use an index on ItemName, but this makes the query a little more complicated.

If the data could have non-numeric values after CA40, one can use range matching with LIKE to avoid errors : `LIKE 'CA40[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'`

Comment: Thanks Graham, I used a combination of your answer and @Jatin's.  `WHERE ItemName LIKE 'CA4____'` to only look match items with the desired number of characters as any values with suffixes are not part of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

There's *no* guarantee on the evaluation order of individual predicates in the `WHERE` clause<sup>*</sup>. (Nor does SQL Server guarantee not to evaluate expressions in the `SELECT` clause for values that should be filtered by the `WHERE` clause).

The strongest way to guarantee that your filters take effect is, unfortunately, to split your query into two separate queries - your first query performing the required filtering and putting its results into a temp table/table variable and your second query building from that and performing data conversions.<sup>1</sup>

The slightly weaker way that *almost always works, except sometimes with aggregates it can be a bit funny*<sup>2</sup> is to use `CASE` expressions instead:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN iid.DepartmentCode = 'Filters'
AND ItemName LIKE 'CA4%____'
THEN CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT)
ELSE 60000 END) + 1
FROM InventoryItem ii
JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid
  ON ii.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode
WHERE CASE WHEN iid.DepartmentCode = 'Filters'
AND ItemName LIKE 'CA4%____'
THEN CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT)
ELSE 60000 END < 41000
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This goes against the usual advice to build a single large query and let the optimizer find the best *way* of evaluating your query. Unfortunately, the optimizer often gets this one wrong and there's no indication that Microsoft plan to fix this since it's been a [known issue for more than a decade](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)<sup>+</sup>.

Note that any answer purporting to fix this just by *rearranging* the query (such as placing parts into subqueries) or *adding* additional guard clauses may superficially appear to fix the problem by accidentally forcing the optimizer to choose a different plan. But you've got no guarantee over if or when the optimizer will return to using a plan that does generate the error message again.

<sup>2</sup>[`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql): "In some situations, an expression is evaluated before a CASE statement receives the results of the expression as its input. Errors in evaluating these expressions are possible. Aggregate expressions that appear in WHEN arguments to a CASE statement are evaluated first, then provided to the CASE statement."

<sup>*</sup>Unlike some other programming languages, SQL offers no guarantee such as left-to-right evaluation, nor any way to influence whether or not it exhibits any short-circuiting behaviour.

<sup>+</sup>This issue was originally reported on User Voice. Unfortunately, in it's migration to the Azure feedback forum a lot of detail has been compressed into the single Microsoft "response" which makes it difficult to read, and "oh dear" also lost the substantial votes it had previously received on User Voise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, change the condition in where clause to check only four characters after `CA4`

```
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT)) + 1
FROM InventoryItem ii
JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid
  ON ii.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode
WHERE iid.DepartmentCode = 'Filters'
AND ItemName LIKE 'CA4____'
AND CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT) < 41000
```

Still above query may fail if execution plan chose to evaluate the condition `CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT) < 41000` first. To be fail safe you can use below query.

```
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT)) + 1
FROM 
(   SELECT ItemName
    FROM InventoryItem ii
    JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid
      ON ii.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode
    WHERE iid.DepartmentCode = 'Filters'
    AND ItemName LIKE 'CA4____'
) AS SubQ
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT) < 41000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
MAX(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, 'CA', ''),'-S','') AS INT)) + 1
```

In place of

```
MAX(CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT)) + 1
```

And for

```
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(name, 'CA', ''),'-S','') AS INT)
```

in place

```
CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNUMERIC` if you want to remove any rows with unexpected values, such as having an unknown character in it.

```
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT)) + 1
FROM InventoryItem ii
JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid
  ON ii.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode
WHERE iid.DepartmentCode = 'Filters'
AND ItemName LIKE 'CA4%____'
AND ISNUMERIC(CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '')) = 1 AND CAST(REPLACE(ItemName, 'CA', '') AS INT) < 41000.
```

Note: `ISNUMERIC` is not perfect. It will consider some characters as numeric too. You can read it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121225074805/http://www.sqlhacks.com/Retrieve/Isnumeric-problems).